# How to depict the "include" & "extend" link between use cases in sequence and activity diagrams

Tags: uml, software-design, use-case, rhapsody

I have a problem in "include" & "extend" relation between my principal use cases.

I`m using IBM Rational harmony-SE in IBM rhapsody tools. The issue is, how to depict the link between them self, in activity or in sequence diagrams?

In rhapsody, when you want to create a sequence diagram of a use cases, you can  use Harmony Toolkit that draws automatically do that, but in a generated Sequence diagram, Harmony Toolkit doesn't consider the "include" and "extend" relation between use cases.

How can I solve this?

Comment: This is a partial duplicate. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36525662/2596664 for a correct explanation for activity diagrams.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [include and exclude in Activity diagram](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515778/include-and-exclude-in-activity-diagram)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Disclaimer

There is no definite answer to this question. This is only one of possibilities, however fully conforming UML and working quite well. Moreover it doesn't provide redundancy in models (each UC flow is defined at most once and the included/extending ones are the only referenced).

## Activity diagram

On UC Activity Diagram use Action that is a call to included/extending UC Activity (as part of your flow). Depending if it's includes or extends the action will either have to happen for includes (i.e. it'll be on a flow that is always executed or on all alternative flows) or will be possible to use either a flow containing it or not for extends (i.e. it will be on only some but not all of alternative flows).

## Sequence diagram

On UC Sequence Diagram use Interaction Use block (ref), referencing the included/extending UC Sequence Diagram. Like for Activity Diagram it will either have to happen for includes or be on only some of Combined Fragment sections allowing to pass the whole sequence either including or omitting the referenced part for extends.

## Note about automated generation

I don't think there is any diagram generation tool that will automatically support inclusion/extension on Activity Diagram or Sequence Diagram of a UC and there are many reasons for that. You'll have to draw diagrams yourself or correct the automatically generated ones accordingly.